# If product doesn't belong to this category do this

Tags: product, php, category

So I'm trying to display some content only if the product doesn't belong to a certain category.
I know how to do this if the product DOES belong to the category, so I would do this:

```
<?php
if(in_array(354, $_product->getCategoryIds())){
    echo "<span>" . $_product->getDescription() . "</span>";
}
?>
```

But not sure how to do this so to display the description only if the product DOESN'T belong to this category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `!` before `in_array`:

```
if (!in_array(354, $_product->getCategoryIds())) {
    echo "<span>" . $_product->getDescription() . "</span>";
}
```